# Is there a way to declaratively configure the classpath used by maven itself (specifically to configure which slf4j implementation maven uses)?

Tags: java, maven, logging, maven-profiles

What I am trying to do is to configure the logging implementation used by maven.

(i.e. mvn itself, not the project being built/tested).

I know that I can do this by dropping logback jars into $MAVEN_HOME/libexec/lib and dropping logback.xml into $MAVEN_HOME/confi/logging, but I would like to know whether there is a declarative way to do this, which doesn't involve physically copying jars.

I had the impression that this kind of thing might be possible using maven profiles but this seems like something which would need to be set before the mvn process is even started.

Comment: Possible, but, the [official documentation says](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html#changing-the-slf4j-implementation) "it is simply a matter of removing the slf4j-simple JAR from the lib directory and replacing it with one of the alternative implementations", and does not suggest a pure configuration change.

Comment: thank you @Joe . Yes I was able to get it to work by replacing the jar. I was thinking ahead to when need to get this working for only certain builds on a shared TeamCity instance.